# I want to search/fetch five Smallest values along with there 'Name Headers' from a row where week is equal to current week

Tags: excel, algorithm

I have an Excel file and want to search/fetch five smallest values along with their 'Name Headers' from a row where week is equal to current week. My sample sheet layout:

```
  _A_   _B_    _C_    _D_    _E_    _F_    _G_    _H_    _I_
3|Week Level1 Level2 Level3 Level4 Level5 Level6 Level7 Level8
4| 1    13%     33%    50%    50%    50%
5| 2    80%     55%    50%    50%    50%   50%
6| 3    75%     5%     50%    50%    50%   50%
7| 4    50%     55%    50%    50%    50%   50%
8| 5    50%     50%    50%    50%    50%   50%
9| 6    50%     12%    15%    80%    5%    65%    45%     1%
```

Result should be like this:

1%Level8, 5%Level5, 12%Level2, 15%Level3,45%Level7

Current week = 6 (Is in cell B2)

I'm able to search five smallest values using INDEX and MATCH but I'm unable to fetch name header of smallest value.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the the 5 smallest percentages in `K2:K6` with this formula in `K2` copied down

`=IFERROR(SMALL(INDEX(B$4:I$9,MATCH(B$2,A$4:A$9,0),0),ROWS(K$2:K2)),"")`

Then in `L2` copied down to get the header values, **taking into account that some of the 5 lowest %s might be duplicated**

`=IF(K2="","",INDEX(B$3:I$3,SMALL(IF(INDEX(B$4:I$9,MATCH(B$2,A$4:A$9,0),0)=K2,COLUMN(B$3:I$3)-COLUMN(B$3)+1),COUNTIFS(K$2:K2,K2))))`

This latter formula needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Dear Barry..Thank you for your reply. The first past of formula is working fine but second formula in which we tried to fetch Name Header is not working. It gives NUM error in few cells & for rest of the values its fetching wrong Name header. Can you please recheck as I think it should work.

Comment: It certainly works OK for me - have you confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER so that the formula is surrounded with curly braces like { and } ? Have you altered the formula at all or are you using excatly the version I posted?

Comment: Yes I did altered the formula as per my original sheet & I did used CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to execute formula.

Comment: Can you post the formula you are now using for the first cell in the second column?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I want the result in row for example incase of above table the result should appear in J4:k4:L4:M4:N4 and moreover I want to CONCATENATE five smallest value with there levels. The result would be appearing row wise some what like this 1%Level8, 5%Level5, 12%Level2, 15%Level3,45%Level7.

Comment: Your algorithm is fetching data in column where as i want result in a row as mentioned in my previous post. The formula is working in row as well but problem comes when two levels have same value than it refers to same level for both i think there is some change required COUNTIF as counter doesn't work in ROW but it's working perfectly in COLUMN.